# Склонение фамилий

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как склонять фамилию Коломеец в мужском роде и множественном числе?

Answer (score 2):

Склоняется как "индеец" или "гвардеец".

В единственном:
И. кто? Иван Коломеец
Р. кого? Ивана Коломейца
Д. кому? Ивану Коломейцу 
В. кого? Ивана Коломейца
Т. кем? Иваном Коломейцем
П. (о) ком? (об)Иване Коломейце

*Обратите внимание на творительный падеж.* Поскольку ударение скорее всего в исходной форме падает на первое е: Колом*е*ец и не смещается, то окончание творительного падежа - **ем**.

Во множественном так же склоняется:

И. кто? Иван и Мария Коломейцы
Р. кого? Ивана и Марии Коломейцев
Д. кому? Ивану и Марии Коломейцам 
В. кого? Ивана и Марии Коломейцев
Т. кем? Иваном и Марией Коломейцами
П. (о) ком? (об)Иване и Марии Коломейцах

Причин для несуществования формы множественного числа фамилии или её несклонения во множественном я не вижу никаких.

Что касается сочетаний типа "братья Коломеец", "семья Коломеец" - то тут сложнее. Действительно, есть разночтения в рекомендациях, некоторые авторы предлагают свести к случаю иностранных фамилий, где наблюдаются не совсем формализованные колебания в зависимости от пола "составляющих" и их семейных отношений. Типа "братья Форды", но "семья Клинтон".

И все же я за варианты "братья Коломейцы", "семья Коломейцев" и т.п. поскольку фамилия явно восточнославянская (едва ли не русская) и никаких сомнений в восстановлении исходной формы не вызывает.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Интересную информацию по теме можно найти по этой ссылке http://www.semfamily.ru/index.php/sdnemrozhdeniya/90-famez

Получается, что фамилия в м.р. склоняется Коломеец - Коломейца. Во множественном числе фамилия, скорее всего, не склоняется: семья Коломеец - семью Коломеец.